# Branch names not showing in Mercurial's tab completion

Tags: bash, python, mercurial, tab-completion

I have a development machine running mercurial 1.6.3. Tab completion in bash works great for completing commands, tags and branch names. I've set up a new machine with the same mercurial version (both running python 2.6), but when I try to use tab completion, I only get hg commands and tags to show - no branch name. Is there anything I need to configure to have branch names included as well? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem on OSX El Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04.

In Ubuntu I originally manually patched `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hg`. But as System Files were protected on OSX I setup [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) which is probably a better solution then touching zsh system files. You can make these modifications straight to the `_hg` file if you do not want to use zsh.

After installing `oh-my-zsh` I copied `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hg` to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/hg/_hg`.

Then modified the `_hg` file replacing the _hg_tags() function with

```
_hg_tags() {
  local expl
  typeset -a hglabels
  hglabels=( ${(f)"$(_hg_cmd debugnamecomplete -q 2>/dev/null)"} )
  _wanted labels expl 'labels' compadd -a - hglabels
}
```

To get zsh to load it modify `~/.zshrc` and add `hg` to the `plugins=(... hg)` section.

You may want to modify other functions to use _hg_tags. I found after using it a bit `_hg_cmd_merge` needed to be updated to use `_hg_tags`.

```
_hg_cmd_merge() {
  _arguments -s -w : $_hg_global_opts \
  '(--force -f)'{-f,--force}'[force a merge with outstanding changes]' \
  '(--rev -r 1)'{-r,--rev}'[revision to merge]:revision:_hg_tags' \
  '(--preview -P)'{-P,--preview}'[review revisions to merge (no merge is performed)]' \
  ':revision:_hg_tags'
}
```